# How do I insert a blank line every n lines using awk?

Tags: awk, blank-line

I've got an input file like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

I'd like to use awk to insert a blank line every few lines; for example, every two:

```
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4

line 5
line 6
```

How can I get awk to put a blank line into my file every n lines?

Answer (score 30):

A more "awk-ish" way to write smcameron's answer:

```
awk -v n=5 '1; NR % n == 0 {print ""}'
```

The "1;" is a condition that is always true, and will trigger the default action which is to print the current line.

Comment: Same here, no? print line and print newline would need to be reversed, otherwise the newline is print before every 5th line instead of after it.

Comment: I would probably write that as `'{print} NR % n == 0 { print "" }`, but that is purely a style issue.

Answer (score 20):

```
awk '{ if ((NR % 5) == 0) printf("\n"); print; }'
```

for `n == 5`, of course.  Substitute whatever your idea of `n` is.

Comment: If n=1, the following seem to work:
`awk '{print; printf("\n");}'` or simply 
`awk '{print; print "";}'`

Comment: This will put the first new line before the 5th line instead of after is. print and the printf need to be reversed..

Answer (score 7):

More awkishness:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%5?RS:RS RS'
```

For example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..12} | awk 'ORS=NR%5?RS:RS RS'
1
2
3
4
5

6
7
8
9
10

11
12
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{print; if (FNR % 5 == 0 ) printf "\n";}' your_file
```

I guess 'print' should be before 'printf', and FNR is more accurate for your task.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v n=5 '$0=(!(NR%n))?"\n"$0:$0'
```

If you want to change 'n', please set the parameter 'n' by awk's -v option.

Comment: That will be problematic when a line is blank or consists of a zero.